# Asignar valor por defecto al destructurar arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Querría saber cómo poner un valor por defecto para la constante `b`, tengo que hacer un ejercicio 'deconstruyendo' arrays, pero `b` ya está asignada como constante y no sé cómo hacer que valga 2 sin tocar esta línea de código. Intenté `let [,b] = [a,b,c]` pero obviamente no va y no sé cómo es.

Debe pasar este testing con Jasmine:

```js
describe('destructuring can also have default values. ', () => {
  it('for a missing value', () => {
    const [a,b,c] = [1,,3];
    expect(b).toEqual(2);
  });
});

// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```

Comment: Quieres declarar a "b" con un valor de 2 usando "destructuring"? Me dejo confuso la pregunta

Comment: Hola Francisco, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general). Échale un ojo a [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], y luego edita la pregunta siguiendo las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí. Tal y como está redactada ahora, no termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres hacer o qué es lo que has intentado. Un saludo.

Comment: Francisco, tu pregunta no se entiende. De todos modos, [puedes leer aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment), si tienes alguna duda sobre *Destructuring*.

Comment: eso es federico, en un primer momento b es undefined pero necesito que valga 2, usando valores por defecto cuando hago destructuring

Comment: A. Cedano actualice la pregunta, esto es lo que pide jasmine que se cumpla y no sabria como

Comment: ¿Dónde se le asigna el valor a `b`? Deberías poner un ejemplo más completo para poder ver dónde está el error exactamente. Lee [mcve] y edita la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede sin tocar la línea donde se toca la asignación: La única manera de definir valores por defecto a las variables o parámetros es cuando se declaran.

```js
//Si no se pasa un valor, b valdrá 2
function porDefecto([a,b = 2,c]) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
}

let miArray = [1,,3];

porDefecto(miArray);


//Si no se pasa un valor, b valdrá 5
const [a = 0,b = 5, c= 2]=miArray;
console.log(a,b,c);
```

Fuera de la declaración, ya se considera una asignación normal:

```js
let miArray = [1,,3];


//No pueden ser constantes o b no podría ser reasignada a 2
let [a, b, c]=miArray;
b = b || 2;
console.log(a,b,c);
```